what is logic of Click outside event in composable Vuejs?
I use `vueuse/core` for detecting click outside event
I have two code snippets that can I can not understand the logic behind the scenes.
The first snippet:
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { onClickOutside } from "@vueuse/core";

const showMobileNav = ref(false);
const navbarMenuRef = ref(null);
/**
 * click outside to close
 */
const navbarBurgerRef = ref(null);

onClickOutside(navbarMenuRef, () => {
  showMobileNav.value = false;
});


</script>
<template>
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item is-size-4 is-family-monospace">Noteballs</div>

        <a
          @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav"
          :class="{ 'is-active': showMobileNav }"
        > 
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div
        class="navbar-menu"
        :class="{ 'is-active': showMobileNav }"
        ref="navbarMenuRef"
      >
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <router-link @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav" to="/" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active"
            >Notes</router-link
          >
          <router-link @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav" to="/stats" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active"
            >Stats</router-link
          >
        </div>
      </div>
</template>

The second snippet. After changing the logic with `vueuse` library
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { onClickOutside } from "@vueuse/core";

const showMobileNav = ref(false);
const navbarMenuRef = ref(null);
/**
 * click outside to close
 */
const navbarBurgerRef = ref(null);

onClickOutside(navbarMenuRef, () => {
  showMobileNav.value = false;
}, {
  ignore: [navbarBurgerRef],
});


</script>
<template>
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item is-size-4 is-family-monospace">Noteballs</div>

        <a
          @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav"
          :class="{ 'is-active': showMobileNav }"
          ref="navbarBurgerRef"
        > 
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div
        class="navbar-menu"
        :class="{ 'is-active': showMobileNav }"
        ref="navbarMenuRef"
      >
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <router-link @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav" to="/" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active"
            >Notes</router-link
          >
          <router-link @click="showMobileNav = !showMobileNav" to="/stats" class="navbar-item" active-class="is-active"
            >Stats</router-link
          >
        </div>
      </div>
</template>

First snippet. I press the burger icon, the menu is not hide
Second snippet, I press the burger icon, the menu is hide
Those changes in second snippet are:

add option ignore to onClickOutside method
add ref="navbarBurgerRef" to class="navbar-menu"

Can anyone explain to me. Thanks

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

@EstusFlask, I'm trying to describe my issue.

Thanks, can you clarify which snippet works the intended way?

@EstusFlask , I updated

"ignore" makes this handler ignore a specific element, as the name suggests. If you don't ignore a click on navbarBurgerRef, this is supposed to result in changing showMobileNav twice, in @click and outside handlers

you can say more detail about two part, I can't imagine

When you click without ignore in snippet 1, both showMobileNav.value = false and showMobileNav = !showMobileNav are executed, probably in this order based on your description, but it's undetermined. You can debug both listeners to make it clear. If you want to avoid this situation then ignore is the correct thing to do
